# Angular custom directive not being called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular and am currently converting my conventional html/javascript website into an Angular application.

I am stuck on a custom directive where the problem is that it is not rendering in the view.

From reading the angular docs, I understand the camel-casing convention and that if you don't have the 'restrict' property set, Angular will automatically assume that its an attribute so I know that there are no issues there.

Here is how I have structured my directive:

```
var directives = angular.module('app.directives', []);
directives.directive("dataPercent", [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<a href="http://google.com">Click me to go to Google </a> '

    }
}]);
```

How it is in the DOM:

```
<data-percentage></data-percentage>
```

And the reference to the directive in the header of index.html

```
<script src="assets/directives/dataPercentDirective.js"></script>
```

Also just in case this is how I init my controllers, directives and services in app.js:

```
angular.module('app', ['app.controllers', 'app.directives', 'app.services']);
```

The strange part is that there are no errors displayed in dev tools

Comment: Use directive in DOM as :   <dataPercent></dataPercent>

Comment: No that will not render because of camel casing

Comment: did u see any error on your browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `datPercent` as data is reserved keyword

> data is reserved keyword.

jsbin http://jsbin.com/yexonayoho/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @DecompileCodex If it is right answer, don't hesitate to mark it correct :)